# Duplicate entries based on values in key/value pair table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a key/value pair table

```
Create Table mat_characteristics
(
 material varchar(100),
 characteristic varchar(100),
 characteristic_value varchar(100)
)
GO

Insert into mat_characterstics values
('113567','height','20.3'),
('113567','weight','11.3'),
('113567','diameter','6.3'),
('113567','length','6.3'),
('113564','height','20.3'),
('113564','length','2.3'),
('113564','length','6.3'),
('113565','height','20.3'),
('113565','weight','11.3'),
('113565','weight','2.3'),
('113565','weight','7.3'),
('113565','diameter','6.3'),
('113565','length','6.3'),
('113545','height','20.3'),
('113545','weight','11.3'),
('113545','weight','2.3'),
('113545','weight','7.3'),
('113545','diameter','6.3'),
('113545','length','6.3');
```

If you see the 113565 and 113545 materials are having the same characteristics and characteristic_value. According to our business rules, no two materials should be having the same characteristics and characteristic_value. And in my real case scenario, materials sometimes will be having nearly 1000 characteristics.

please help me to get the bad records identified.

---

I tried making the rows into columns using this query but this is resulting in more than 1300 columns and I am not sure how to proceed after this

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
--@ColumnName is used to store the maximum number of column names
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- Creating temporary table
select * into #tmpmat_characterstics
from 
(select material, characterstic,characterstic_value,characterstic+cast(row_number() over (partition by material,characterstic order by characterstic) as varchar(45)) as ColumnSequence from mat_characterstics) mat_characterstics

select @ColumnName= COALESCE(@ColumnName+ ', ','') + QUOTENAME(columnsequence)
from 
(
select distinct columnsequence from #tmpmat_characterstics
) test


set @DynamicPivotQuery= 

'select material, ' +@ColumnName+ 'from #tmpmat_characterstics
PIVOT
(
    max(characterstic_value)
    for ColumnSequence in (' +@ColumnName+ ')
) PIV'


EXEC(@DynamicPivotQuery);
```

Comment: I would not use dynamic SQL for this, under you have some extenuating circumstance that required it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method is `string_agg()`:

```
select characteristics, count(*),
       string_agg(material, ',') as materials
from (select material,
             string_agg(concat(characteristic, ':', characteristic_value), ',') as characteristcs
      from mat_characteristics
      group by material
     ) m
group by characteristics
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce this in SQL Server with an indexed view.  EG

```
use tempdb
drop table if exists mat_characteristics
drop view if exists v_mat_mat_characterstics_enforce_uniqueness
go
Create Table mat_characteristics
(
 material varchar(100),
 characteristic varchar(100),
 characteristic_value varchar(100)
)
GO

Insert into mat_characteristics values
('113567','height','20.3'),
('113567','weight','11.3'),
('113567','diameter','6.3')

go
create or alter view v_mat_mat_characterstics_enforce_uniqueness
with schemabinding
as
select material, characteristic, characteristic_value, COUNT_BIG(*) rows
from dbo.mat_characteristics
group by  material, characteristic, characteristic_value
go
create unique clustered index ci_v_mat_mat_characterstics_enforce_uniqueness
  on v_mat_mat_characterstics_enforce_uniqueness(characteristic, characteristic_value)
go
Insert into mat_characteristics values
('113567','length','6.3'),
('113564','height','20.3'),
('113564','length','2.3'),
('113564','length','6.3'),
('113565','height','20.3'),
('113565','weight','11.3'),
('113565','weight','2.3'),
('113565','weight','7.3'),
('113565','diameter','6.3'),
('113565','length','6.3'),
('113545','height','20.3'),
('113545','weight','11.3'),
('113545','weight','2.3'),
('113545','weight','7.3'),
('113545','diameter','6.3'),
('113545','length','6.3');
```

The second insert fails with

```
Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 29
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.v_mat_mat_characterstics_enforce_uniqueness' with unique index 'ci_v_mat_mat_characterstics_enforce_uniqueness'. The duplicate key value is (diameter, 6.3).
The statement has been terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would find the duplicates first and then join the original table to find out the materials:

```
select mc.material, mc.characteristic, mc.characteristic_value
from (  --  find all duplicate sets of characteristic and characteristic_value
   select characteristic, characteristic_value
   from mat_characteristics
   group by characteristic, characteristic_value
   having count(*) > 1
) a
inner join mat_characteristics mc -- inner join the original table to get the materials
   on mc.characteristic = a.characteristic
   and mc.characteristic_value = a.characteristic_value
order by mc.characteristic, mc.characteristic_value, mc.material
```